# Identify which polygon contains a point with Django?

Tags: python, django, polygon, geodjango, intersect

I need to identify quickly to which polygons a set of points belong in Django 1.9.

First option is to loop through all polygons and check which points they contain:

```
for countrypolygon in countrypolygons:
    placesinthecountry = Place.objects.filter(lnglat__intersects=countrypolygon.geom)
```

This takes a lot of time as I need to loop through a lot of polygons.

Is it possible to do the opposite, i.e. loop through each point and immediately get the polygons in which it is contained?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#contains):

```
for point in my_points:
    polygons = MyModel.objects.filter(geom__contains=point.geom)
```